# How to properly export and re-import GPG secret key and all its subkeys?

Tags: gnupg

I have 2 YubiKeys and want one of them to be a backup. So let's say I generated a key `$KEY` in my computer with an encryption subkey. I need to export the secret keys, because when moving them to the card they disappear, and then reimport them.

So I export them with

```
gpg2 -a -o secmain.asc --export-secret-key --armor $KEY
gpg2 -a -o secsub.asc --export-secret-subkeys --armor $KEY
```

move them to the card, and then re-import them with:

```
gpg2 --import secmain.asc
gpg2 --import secsub.asc
```

I would expect this to work (as this is what was in the tutorial I read), but on the second import GPG tells me that the key was not changed, so I don't have my encryption key back. After searching a bit I found out about the `--export-secret-keys` option, which I assumed would export main and all sub keys in one package, but on import encryption subkey is still missing.

How can this be done?

**EDIT**

After further discussions, I tried to generate default keys and those I can correctly import/export. Then I the keys with my preferred settings manually and they also imported well. So it turns out this issue only occurs when I generate a key using this command:

```
gpg2 --batch --gen-key <<EOF
Key-Type: EdDSA
Key-Curve: ed25519
Key-Usage: sign
Subkey-Type: ECC
Subkey-Curve: Ed25519
Subkey-Usage: encrypt
Name-Real: My Name
Name-Comment: uname
Name-Email: my@email.tld
Expire-Date: 0
EOF
```

What gives? What's wrong here, and if it is, why isn't there a warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> GPG tells me that the key was not changed

That is because the the secret subkeys should already be imported with the first command. You can verify with `gpg --list-packets secmain.asc` that the full key was exported.

The output generated by `--export-secret-subkeys` is superfluous (and will contain an unusable primary secret key).

> on import encryption subkey is still missing

Check the output of `gpg --list-secret-keys`

### EDIT

> What's wrong here

I would suspect this:

> Subkey-Curve: Ed25519

... being combined with this:

> Subkey-Usage: encrypt

I'm not sure how gpg handles this internally, since there is no way to create an "ed25519" encryption key using interactive mode. If you instead use `Subkey-Curve cv25519` the key should export and import without issue.

Comment: `gpg --list-packets secmain.ascc` indeed contains data of a subkey, however upon importing the encryption key is not marked as `ssb` but `ssb#` and I cannot perform any operations with it with gpg complaining about it being unusable. Furthermore, if I try to repeat the operation to move the key to card, I end up with no key in the card.

Comment: The `#` is a pointer indicating the key is on a card. Check the output of `gpg --list-packets secmain.asc`  - do you see a line with `gnu-divert-to-card` in the secret subkey area?

Comment: No such string there. Also:
1) I export the key before I move it to the card. How would it know I would move it there?
2) I did `rm -r .gnupg` before import with the same results
3) I thought it was `>` that meant it was on the card

Comment: You are correct `>` is the pointer, not `#`. The hashtag usually means the key is expired or has been revoked. Are either of these the case?

Comment: Nope :/ they were created with no expiration date (and why would it expire only after import?) and I don't even know how to revoke keys. I don't intend to use PKI, I just want to encrypt stuff with my Yubikey and have a spare.

Comment: In the `gpg --list-packets secmain.asc` output do you see `gnu-dummy S2K` anywhere in the secret subkey section?

Comment: I see `iter+salt S2K, algo: 7, SHA1 protection, hash: 2, salt: 57026348EE3E1895`. I see the `gnu-dummy S2K` if I export the key after reimport, though.

Comment: If you generate a new key using the gpg you are trying to import to, then export that full key to a file with `export-secret-keys`, then delete the key from your keyring with `--delete-secret-and-public-key`, then import it from the file, does that key also have the same issue with the secret subkey?

Comment: Sadly, yes it does :(
I also noticed something else, I tried to add a password using `pass` and it says `[stdin]: encryption failed: Unusable public key` yet `gpg2 -k` shows a normal summary (with the encryption key tagged as sub and no other symbols)

Comment: What is the output of `gpg --version`? I wonder will there be a difference if you replace `gpg2` with `gpg` in all commands (`gpg --import secmain.asc`, `gpg -K`, etc.). Most systems only have Gnupg 2.x installed these days (Gnupg 1.x is no longer maintained) and don't require specifying gpg2.

Comment: `gpg` doesn't exist on my system. I'm using Void Linux, gpg version 2.2.27, libgcrypt 1.9.2

Comment: If you generate a new key on the system you are trying to import to, does `gpg2 -K` show the ssb key is usable (no #)? Can you edit and add a password to it? Does `gpg2 --export-secret-keys KEYID | gpg2 --list-packets` show the secret subkey contains a real S2K specifier and not `gnu-dummy S2K`?

Comment: There is no other system, I need to re-import it so that I move it to the other card. I can try to do that, just to check, but only on Monday will I have access to another system. Oh, and thanks a lot for the effort! :)

Comment: Oh, right. I started thinking about it in the context of how I always migrate secret keys (one pc/installation to another). Since this occurs on the same installation and even new secret keys can't be imported the only thing I can think is to verify the .gnupg/private-keys-v1.d/ directory is empty then try again importing the key from the secmain.asc file that contains the entire key as verified by list-packets. Try `gpg2 --no-options --import secmain.asc` to be sure there's not strange configuration options in effect.

Comment: It still didn't work, but I noticed that one of the keys in .gnupg/private-keys-v1.d/ didn't match the keygrips I had (I don't know if they should), so I tried default keys and it worked. Please check the edit in the question.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know the key was being generated with batch mode. See edited answer.

Comment: FInally! I guess this is a bug. If I input `Subkey-Curve: x25519` it complains that it doesn't know that curve. If it can't handle the combination ed25519/encrypt then it should say so. Or at least have proper documentation that lists these values.